# Flutter: Is there a way to create a container that is always there

Tags: flutter

I am currently working with a TabBar in Flutter. Is there a way to create a container that is always there, no matter in which Tab you are currently in. To be specific I only want one Container to change its content after the tab click, the other ones should stay the same.

Comment: Where do you want this Container to be shown?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer! Already got the answered here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not completely clear what do you need. But try to create this *"mandatory"* container as separate widget and place it in every `Tab` widget.

**Tab 1 widget**

```dart
return Column(
  children: [
    PermanentWidget(), // <-- this widget will be the same always
    ModifiableWidgetOnTabOne()
  ],
);
```

**Tab 2 widget**

```dart
return Column(
  children: [
    PermanentWidget(), // <-- this widget will be the same always
    ModifiableWidgetOnTabTwo()
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. Sorry for my bad explanation.